# how to load OpenSocial gadgets libraries in javascript?

Tags: javascript, yahoo, yql, opensocial

I'm using a version of the sample code from [YQL Code Examples](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_javascript) in order to retrieve Yahoo! contacts. My specific problem is that the sample code includes OpenSocial gadgets functions, and I'm unable to find the javascript library to be included in order to use the function gadgets.io.makeRequest. The final question is: what is the url of the script to be included in my page in order to be able to execute the code gadgets.io.makeRequest(...). Thanks in advance